# Adding SVG dynamically in Ionic 2, how to add an onclick-function?

Tags: typescript, svg, ionic2

I'm working on an app in Ionic 2. Reading data about keyboards of musical instruments from a JSON-File, I dynamically add circle-objects to the svg, which is implemented in the instrument-detail.html-file. This works fine in the instrument-detail.ts:

```
var circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
circle.setAttribute('id', this.keyIndex.toString());
circle.setAttribute('cx', posX.toString());
circle.setAttribute('cy', posY.toString());
circle.setAttribute('r', radius.toString());
circle.setAttribute('class', 'buttonStandard');
svg.appendChild(circle);
```

Now I want to add some action to the circles when touched, calling a method doSomething() in instrument-detail.ts.

```
circle.setAttribute('class', '(click)="doSomething()"');
```

doesn't work, I think, I know why...

```
circle.setAttribute('class', 'onclick="doSomething()"');
```

leads to an runtime-error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: doSomething is not defined at SVGCircleElement.onclick
```

Any idea how to fix my problem? How to address the method correctly?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:
add an eventlistener:

```
circle.addEventListener("click", function() {           // Attach desired event
                          let myId= this.id.split('_')[0];
                          alert(myId+": Moving to page #"+myId);

                      }, false);
```